# How to calculate Mahalanobis distance in very high dimensions with both continuous and categorical variables?

Tags: machine-learning, outliers, feature-engineering, distance-functions

The objective is outlier detection via a distance measure.

1. Does mahalanobis distance suffer from curse of dimensionality just like Eucledian distance for 
   very high dimensions? (say around 5000 variables)
2. My dataset has both continuous and discrete variables. How do I calculate M-distance?

I can think of 2 options:

```
a) calculate mahalanobis distance on continuous variables + dummy variables 
b) calculate the distance only for continuous variables 
   (i'm guessing b) would provide the right measure and option a) is unnecessary)
```